# crosstab query with multiple tables

Tags: ms-access

I have a database of students from four different schools, their families, and participation in different activities. Relevant to this question are a two queries:

- student_family connects students and their families members on fam_ID (primary key in Family table, foreign in student table)
- a participation query collects each instance of participation by each family linked through student ID (primary key in student table).

I currently have a crosstab query (based on the student_family query) that shows each family's parent info and a count of how many students that family has at each school (pivot is on school)

I'd like to add a column that displays either a count of the number of activities participated in per family, or simply YES/NO based on whether or not a family has participated in an event. I've made this happen by linking the participation query, but in linking it, instead of giving me a count of the number of students per school per family, the crosstab values start displaying the number of activities per school per family.

So it goes from looking like this:

**family** -- **school 1** -- **school 2** -- **school 3**

smith -- 1 -- 1 -- 0

to looking like this

**family** -- **activity yes/no** -- **school 1** -- **school 2** -- **school 3**

smith -- YES -- 9 -- 4 -- 0

Is there any way to keep the crosstab values based only on the number of students in the family, while also referencing the participation table?

Thanks!
Josh

Answer (score 0):

you can make simple demo DB to see the structure and sketch to see the result want. so we can make it directly and fast. your request is easy I think you need the grouping and the sum to make that.